# Assign Static IP Address in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, ethernet, ubuntu-18.04

I want to assign a static address to Ubuntu using the command below:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.5.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

But it says,

```
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
```

How will I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the rule files with this command :

```
sudo mv /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.old
```

Should solve the problem.